# Make 2 constructors depending on Boolean value

Tags: java, android, constructor

This is a really simple question. I'm making a simple Java object for my app as follows:

```
public class Category{
    // STATE
    private String mCategoryName;
    private Boolean mContainsSubcategories;
    private Subcategory[] mSubcategoryList; // Subcategory is another object
    // Constructor
    // for mContainsSubcategories == false, use the below constructor
    public Category(String categoryName, Boolean containsSubcategories){

    }
    // for mContainsSubcategories == true, use the below constructor
    public Category(String categoryName, Boolean containsSubcategories, Subcategory[] subcategoryList){

    }

    // GETTER METHODS
    /* ..................... */
}
```

Basically, what I want is, to use different constructor depending on the Boolean value. If boolean value is true, then use one constructor, if it's false, use the other constructor. How can I do this?

Comment: Then why do you need the boolean param?
You can have the following constructors:
      public Category(String categoryName, Subcategory[] subcategoryList)
and
      public Category(String categoryName)

and you will use the constructors depands if you pass the Subcategories or not.

Comment: I don't think that's what you want. You just want to remove the boolean argument (which should be a boolean, BTW, not a Boolean), and set the boolean field to true in the second constructor is called, and set it to false in the first one. But even then, what's the point of this boolean. You just need to check if the array length is > 0 to know if it has subcategories. No need to duplicate that information.

Comment: Because I want to use a different layout if it contains subcategories...

Comment: Then you just pass or not the subcategories (or check if the its null or empty)

Comment: So what? `public boolean hasSubCategories() { return this.mSubcategoryList.length > 0; }` is all you need to do that. No need for an additional boolean field.

Comment: Oh my god! thanks a lot... that was simple.!
I guess i really need to take a break...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a getinstance method:

```
public class Category{

    // STATE
    private String mCategoryName;
    private Boolean mContainsSubcategories;
    private Subcategory[] mSubcategoryList; // Subcategory is another object
    // Constructor
    public static Category getInstance(boolean mContainsSubcategories,String mCategoryName, Subcategory[] subcategoryList) {
        if (mContainsSubcategories){
            return new Category(mCategoryName);
        }else {
            return new Category(mCategoryName,subcategoryList);
        }
    }
    // for mContainsSubcategories == false, use the below constructor
    public Category(String categoryName){

    }
    // for mContainsSubcategories == true, use the below constructor
    public Category(String categoryName, Subcategory[] subcategoryList){

    }

    // GETTER METHODS
    /* ..................... */
}
```

And to initialize it use:

```
Category myCategory =    
      Category.getInstance(mContainsSubcategories,mCategoryName,subcategoryList); 
                  //instead of new Category
```

Comment: That answers the question very well. Thanks a lot!